# Setting custom X-axis ticks on chart.js line chart for distance vs elevation

Tags: chart.js

I am starting out with Chart.js and trying to make an elevation chart, with distance on the X axis and elevation on the Y axis. I can make the chart using default config, but am having a problem making the X axis ticks more customized. I want X axis labels to go up in whole increments, rather than showing random numbers selected from the data. In other words, I want the X axis to be something like "0 10 20 30 40 50" rather than "0 2.24 11.89 23.54". I am trying to do this as follows, and it works in terms of setting the X axis ticks, but then there's no graph line any more.

```js
    chart = new Chart (canvas_id, {
 type: 'line',
 data: {
     labels: distances,
     datasets: [{
  label: 'Elevations',
  data: elevations
     }
     ]
 },
 options: {
     scales: {
  xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
   callback: function(value, index, values) {
       return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
   },
   autoSkip: true,
   stepSize: increment,
   beginAtZero: true
      }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
   beginAtZero: true
      }
  }]
     }
 }
    });
```

This is what that looks like:

[image: no graph line displayed]

When I take out the type: linear line, then the graph line gets displayed correctly, but the X axis is the default again.

[image: graph line displayed now, but with default x axis ticks]

Can anybody give me a clue how to get to the point where I am able to do a line chart for elevations vs distance, with my own ticks? It seems I can get the line or the x-axis, but not both at the same time. Thanks!